# Modelsim time for falling/rising edge

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

Is there a way do define (in modelsim) the time which a signal needs to go from low-high(rising)/high-low(falling) edge. 
For example to simulate more advanced I would like to define a time for going from low to high at a a single signal clk(e.g. 1 ns).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: ModelSim is a digital simulator, not an analog one. You could emulate some kind of delay or undefined voltage level between '0' and '1' by using other members of the `STD_LOGIC` enum. See Brian's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this would work for a clock.

However you can assign signals like

```
Sig_A <= 'X', '1' after 1 ns;
```

Then anything sampling the signal between `now` and `now + 1 ns` will return `'X'` allowing you to catch the error in simulation.

Synthesis ought to simply treat this assignment as

```
Sig_A <= '1';
```

while probably issuing a warning you can safely ignore.

Note however that if you use `Sig_A` above as a clock, the clock edge will be seen at its second transition (i.e. `now + 1 ns` ) if at all, rather than introducing any timing uncertainty, hence my caution above.

If you need to simulate performance with variable clock timings, what you probably need to do is introduce a generic or a constant in a package, such as

```
entity TB is
generic (T_clkH : time := 1 ns)
end TB;
...
    Clk <= '1' after T_clkH;
```

and run the simulation twice, supplying minimum and maximum values for the generic.

Comment: It's problematic to use other values than '0' and '1' on a clock line, because `rising_edge(clk)` tests for a real 0 -> 1 transition, not an *any* -> 1 transition.

Comment: OK, but it also accepts L -> 1 (as it should), but not H -> 1 (as it shouldn't) unlike that other style. I agree that X->1 is a bad idea....

Comment: Edit to my previous comment: `rising_edge(clk)` tests for `0/L -> 1/H` transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this in my simulations.

```
clk <= not clk after 1 ns;
```

Remember to initialize your signal.

```
signal clk : std_logic := '0';
```